# AngularJS - Mobile Nav - How to install other Controller

Tags: angularjs, mobile, nav

I have Probleme with the Controller. Can you help me with this code? I have the Plugin of the Site: http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/ the first module does not work :/

I would like to include this code of "MainCtrl" in the controller:

```
var roomcatApp = angular.module('roomcatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'roomcatControllers',
  'roomcatFilters',
  'roomcatServices'
]);

roomcatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/rooms', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/room-list.html',
        controller: 'RoomListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/rooms/:roomId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/room-detail.html',
        controller: 'RoomDetailCtrl'
      }).
      when('/rooms/:roomId/map', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/room-list.html',
        controller: 'MapCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/rooms'
      });
  }]);

angular.module('roomcatApp', ['snap'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.snapOpts = {
      disable: 'right'
    };
  });
```

or do I add this part here?

```
var roomcatControllers = angular.module('roomcatControllers', []);

roomcatControllers.controller('RoomListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Room',
  function($scope, Room) {
    $scope.rooms = Room.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';


  }]);

roomcatControllers.controller('RoomDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Room',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Room) {
    $scope.room = Room.get({roomId: $routeParams.roomId}, function(room) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = room.images[0];
    });

    $scope.setImage = function(imageUrl) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
  }]);

roomcatControllers.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Room',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Room) {
    $scope.rooms = Room.query();

    $scope.room = Room.get({roomId: $routeParams.roomId}, function(room) {
    $scope.mainImageUrl = room.images[0];

   });
  }]);
```

Comment: How exactly should work first module and how does it work? Are there any messages in console?

Comment: This is the Error-Message in the console: 

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module roomcatApp due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module snap due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'snap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/nomod?p0=snap minErr/

Comment: Could you show your index.html also?

Comment: Can you check this? This doesn't work -> arekdesign.de/app/index.html

and this works -> http://arekdesign.de/app/sidebar.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you forgot to include [angular-snap.js](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js-bower).

It is specified as a dependency in your `roomcatApp` module:

```
angular.module('roomcatApp', ['snap'])
```

But it is not present in your `index.html` file. Should be included before your app.js and  after angular.js

Also, you should include `js/app.js` after `js/directives`, `js/controllers`, `js/filters`, `js/services`.